# Next.js navigation causes session logout on Django page

Tags: django, authentication, next.js

I am working on an application that combines both Next.js and Django (using django-nextjs package). The authentication is managed by Django using session-based authentication.
Here's the sequence of events leading to the issue:

1. From the homepage (a Next.js page) where I'm not logged in, I navigate to a Django-based login page.
2. After successfully logging in, I get redirected to a Next.js page. So far, everything works correctly, and I can access user data from the session cookie.
3. As long as I navigate between Next.js pages, the session remains active, and I remain logged in.
4. If I manually enter a URL to a Django page that requires authentication or refresh the page, it recognizes my session, and I remain logged in.
5. However, if I navigate to a Django page using the Next.js `<Link />` component, I get logged out instantly.

What's puzzling is that the session seems active and recognized across both frameworks until I navigate to a Django page using `<Link />` . When I do this, Django no longer recognizes my session.

What could be causing the session to be lost? Has anyone faced a similar issue, and how can I fix this?

Other info:
I am using Next JS 13 app router.
This only happens in the production environment. In development, the session remains active, and there are no issues with authentication when navigating via the component.

Answer (score 0):

You should use native html `<a />` links to navigate to external pages which don't belong to your Next.js app router. The `<Link />` component should only be used to navigate between your Next.js routes.

Comment: you are right, this did fix my issue. But i'm curious to what's the cause of this problem.